# Getting error as "Unfortunately we are unable to execute this test suite." in Xamarin Test Cloud

Tags: appium, xamarin-test-cloud

I have written maven project in java in Intellij and updated POM as mentioned in the [link][1].

I have used Appium with Junit.

I haven't added below plugin as they were giving error while uploading package.

```
plugin: org.codehaus.mojo - 
animal-sniffer-maven-plugin and exec-maven-plugin
```

I am getting the following error

#### Checking version

#### Packaging

#### Negotiating upload

#### Uploading negotiated files

Tests enqueued
User: xyz@abc.com
Test Type: Appium
Team: X Team
Running on devices:
    Asus Google Nexus 7 (2013) (6.0.1)

```
### Waiting for test results ###
2017-04-27T12:13:49 Validating
2017-04-27T12:14:00 Validating
2017-04-27T12:14:11 Validating
2017-04-27T12:14:21 Validating
2017-04-27T12:20:31 Running on 1 device (0 / 1 completed, 0 pending)
2017-04-27T12:20:42 Running on 1 device (0 / 1 completed, 0 pending)
2017-04-27T12:20:52 Running on 1 device (0 / 1 completed, 0 pending)
2017-04-27T12:21:03 Running on 1 device (0 / 1 completed, 0 pending)
2017-04-27T12:21:14 Running on 1 device (0 / 1 completed, 0 pending)
2017-04-27T12:21:25 Tests completed. Processing data.
2017-04-27T12:21:36 Failed!
2017-04-27T12:21:36 Reason: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Building run-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ run-
test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ run-test --
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) 
@ run-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 
run-test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ run-test ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: target/run-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:integration-test (default) @ run-
test ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, 
i.e. build is platform dependent! The file encoding for reports output files 
should be provided by the POM property ${project.reporting.outputEncoding}.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:verify (default) @ run-test ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, 
i.e. build is platform dependent! The file encoding for reports output files 
should be provided by the POM property ${project.reporting.outputEncoding}.
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Total time: 3.087 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-27T14:19:57+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/188M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---

2017-04-27T12:21:36 Test Report:
2017-04-27T12:21:36 https://testcloud.xamarin.com/test/asap_b297744a-e560-
4c31-a06d-e06a78ecf61b/
```

Also in Xamarin I get the following error

> Unfortunately we are unable to execute this test suite.

Can someone help me on this?`enter code here`

Comment: Can you replace the console screenshot with the actual text of the error? This makes it easier to work with and search for (if someone else has seen similar errors.)

Comment: I have replaced screenshot with actual text

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm not very familiar with appium myself, but have you confirmed that your setup is consistent with the limitations mentioned in this guide? https://github.com/xamarinhq/test-cloud-appium-java-extensions#4-current-limitations